# blow up time for function $G(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, blowup

given 
$G:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$

$$
G'(t)\geq -\lambda G(t)+ f(G(t))
$$

where $\lambda >0$ and $f$ is a convex function. $G(0)>0$ is also given.

Show that $G$ blows up at finite time $t>0$.

I can see that in case of $f(x)=x^p$ for $p>1$.  Please help me in generalizing it to any convex function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $G(0)>0$ is not enough to guarantee finite time blow up. If $G(u)=u^p$, $p>1$, you need $G(0)>\lambda^{1/(p-1)}$.

Secondly, convexity does not guarantee blow up in finite time. Consider $G(u)=u\log(1+u)$. It is convex, but all solutions are global.

Comment: Sir , Can you help me with this problem . http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144091/second-variation-of-the-domain-functionals . I will remove this comment after some time. I would be glad if i could get your attention.